# Why does Wiko Cink Peax 2 reboot when it receives an SMS containing only '=' (equal sign)?

Tags: sms, reboot, bugs

I have a Wiko Cink Peax 2 and when I receive one SMS with the only character '=' (equal sign), my phone reboots the system. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a known bug that affects majority of Wiko phones. Receiving an SMS with '=' (equal sign) as the only content will soft reset the OS.

References (in French):

- [Quand un simple SMS peut faire redémarrer un téléphone Wiko](http://www.frandroid.com/smartphone/223546_sms-faire-redemarrer-telephone-wiko)
- [Une faille qui fait planter les téléphones Wiko à distance](http://korben.info/faire-planter-telephone-wiko.html)

There is a suggestion from the first site: Use other messaging app, disable the pre-installed messaging app.

Flashing custom ROM **doesn't** seem to fix the issue. It might be caused by hardware issue, but currently there is no update on the real cause.

If it's still in warranty, then maybe it's possible to ask for replacement and ask them to test this issue first.